# How to setup a custom posts page with WPTouch Pro Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a blog using wordpress to display posts not on front page but using a custom template like http://www.koolkatwebdesigns.com/blog/ for desktop or non-mobile. For mobile I am using [WPTouch Pro Plugin](http://www.wptouch.com/) with  Bauhaus theme cannot display posts only show page title like screenshot below:

[image: sswp]

**page-2.php**

```
<?php if ( foundation_is_theme_using_module( 'custom-latest-posts' ) && wptouch_fdn_is_custom_latest_posts_page() ) { ?>

    <?php wptouch_fdn_custom_latest_posts_query(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'index' ); ?>

<?php } else { ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <?php if ( wptouch_have_posts() ) { ?>
            <?php wptouch_the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'page-content' ); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div> <!-- content -->

    <?php if ( wptouch_fdn_show_comments_on_pages() && ( comments_open() || have_comments() ) ) { ?>
        <div id="comments">
            <?php comments_template(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: For debugging you can see if it is getting any results by echoing hello        `<?php echo " Hello "; ?>`   Drop that into the page after each if/else one by one and see where you are.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your help. I just fixed it with myself.

Comment: Funny I was going to suggest that `foundation_is_theme_using_module( 'custom-latest-posts' )` might be something to look at if you didn't have that module - well done! Echo hello has helped me find what is going on in WP quite often - things aren't always doing what you imagine!

Comment: @steve yeah. I didn't use echo to solved my problem but just looking my custom template script (for desktop version) and added with some revision to the script above.

Comment: Well done - often works out like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it with myself like below:

**page-2.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <h2><a href=”<?php wptouch_the_permalink()?>”><?php wptouch_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) { wptouch_the_post(); ?>
<div id="content">
    <div class="post-content">

        <?php query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'post-loop' ); ?>
             <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```